# Separating menu item list from overflow button

Tags: android

I have list of cardviews that has toolbar with overflow menu button. I want to display the menu list separately and at the bottom of the screen, but it appears on the toolbar covering the overflow menu. See images.

Objective: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDZFR.png

Current: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PF1fs.jpg

How am i able to detach the menu items from the toolbar and display it at the bottom on overflow menu click? Please help.Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using menu item with toolbar, Add an overflow image with `onClickListener`.

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/ic_overflow_holo_dark"
    android:contentDescription="@string/descr_overflow_button"
    android:onClick="showPopup" />
```

& you can use this library to show the items

https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet

[Android Bottom/Footer Menu Example with SlideUp Animation](http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/03/android-bottom-footer-menu-example-with-slideup-animation.html)

Comment: Actually i have thought of that and i think that would be my last resort, Youtube app was using the same thing, im not really sure if they are using toolbar. Thanks by the way